# How do I populate an array with random numbers?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to populate an array of four elements with positive integers that are less than 9.

Here is my code:

```
generated_number=Array.new(4)#create empty array of size 4
generated_number.each do |random| #for each position in the array create a random number
  random=rand(10)
end
puts generated_number
```

I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: What is it you are asking?

Comment: I don't understand why when i am using the each method, it doesn't associate the rand(10) to each element in the array

Comment: The problem is that `random=rand(10)` does not actually update the array's values.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can pass a range to `rand()`

```
Array.new(4) { rand(1...9) }
```

Comment: and how should I rewrite my code so that it will work?and also thanks and I will use your solution

Comment: I just ran this on Ruby Fiddle and you need it to be puts `Array.new(4) { Random.rand(1...9) }`

Comment: @J-Dizzle No, when the block will be executed separately for each element.

Comment: @J-Dizzle Ruby Fiddle is a sandboxed environment. My code will work in any normal, non-sandboxed Ruby environment.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're over complicating things.

```
 generated_numbers = 4.times.map{Random.rand(8) } #=> [4, 2, 6, 8]
```

edit: For giggles I put together this function:

```
def rand_array(x, max)
  x.times.map{ Random.rand(max) }
end

puts rand_array(5, 20) #=> [4, 13, 9, 19, 13]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :)
And my code, what was wrong with it? I mean what should be corrected to work?

Comment: Generally, in Ruby, if you can do everything in one line, you should. There's a book called "Eloquent Ruby" that teaches you how to make ruby code that *looks* like ruby code.. otherwise your ruby code will look a lot like java or php code, and that takes some of the coolness out of it.

Comment: `{ rand(8) }` is sufficient.  This is [Kernel#rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand): `method(:rand) #=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#rand>`.

Comment: Though that would be sufficient this code works, and also works in sandboxed environments such as [Ruby Fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/) so I'm not going to edit it out. good point though

Answer (score -1):

## This is how I solved it for an array with 10 elements:

```
n=10
my_array = Array.new(n)
i = 0
loop do 
 random_number = rand(n+1)
 my_array.push(random_number)

 i += 1
 break if i >= n
end

for number in my_array
  puts number
```

Answer (score -1):

This is something I did for a school final, numbers aren't exactly the same but you can change numbers and such:

```
numbers_array = []
10.times do
    numbers_array.push(rand(1..100))
end
puts numbers_array
```